# array loaded twice in gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

please help me guys...
im stuck

i have an array like this

[image]
im trying to put this arrays into gridview with this adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final String[] intelligences;
private final int[] Imageid;

public ImageAdapter(Context c,String[] intelligences,int[] ImageId){
    this.mContext = c;
    this.intelligences=intelligences;
    this.Imageid=ImageId;
}
```

<--getcount, getItem......-->

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textGrid);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageGrid);
        RelativeLayout rl = 
(RelativeLayout)grid.findViewById(R.id.relative);

        textView.setText(intelligences[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);

        Log.i("------position------",String.valueOf(position));
        switch(position){
            case 0:
            rl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, 
R.color.myColor1));
            break;
            case 1:
            rl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, 
R.color.myColor2));
            break;
            case 2:
                rl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, 
R.color.myColor3));
                break;

        }


    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }


    return grid;
}

}
```

and the result is like this

[image]

there are two item loaded twice and some data not loaded,

thanks in advance
sorry about my languange....

Answer (score 0):

solved with this trick

```
if (convertView == null) {
    // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid, null);

} else {
    grid = (View) convertView;
}
TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textGrid);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imageGrid);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) grid.findViewById(R.id.relative);
```